# How to do lodash.find in nested arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, lodash

Here is my array I'm trying to use lodash to find an item:

```
[
  {
    "itemA": "apple",
    "itemB": [
      {
        "itemC": "1",
        "itemD": "red apple"
      },
      {
        "itemC": "2",
        "itemD": "green apple"
      },
      {
        "itemC": "3",
        "itemD": "n/a"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "itemA": "orange",
    "itemB": [
      {
        "itemC": "4",
        "itemD": "big orange"
      },
      {
        "itemC": "5",
        "itemD": "small orange"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "itemA": "grape",
    "itemB": [
      {
        "itemC": "6",
        "itemD": "my grape"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Then I do search this way that works fine:

```
let first = lodash.find(myArray,  {itemA: "apple"});
let second = lodash.find(first.itemB, {itemC: "2"});

if(second)
  console.log(second.itemD);

  output: green apple
```

Question: is there a more graceful way to do that, i.e. combine first and second in one operator? I just worry about performance. Seems the way I do it is not optimal.

Comment: What are you trying to find? What is the input and expected output?

Comment: input apple/2 output "green apple"... See in question

Comment: because itemA = "apple", ItemC = "2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this vanila js solution as well

```
var itemA = "apple";
var itemC = "2";
var output =  myArray.find( s => s.itemA == itemA ).itemB.find( s => s.itemC == itemC ).itemD;
```

In case, the inputs may not available, check for `null`

```
var oItemA = myArray.find( s => s.itemA == itemA );
var oItemB = oItemA ? oItemA.itemB.find( s => s.itemC == itemC ) : null;
var output = oItemB ? oItemB.itemD : "";
```

This will return `"green apple"` for `apple/2` and `""` (empty) for `sapple/3`